# AWS CodePipeline from Github fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3

I am getting the following error on the source stage of my code pipeline:

I feel like I know this means my access token doesn't have access to s3 service, but I do I have created buckets and even ran CLI against it using my access key.

Any tips?

[image]

Action execution failed
GitHub Upload to S3 failed with the following error: The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: KMS.SubscriptionRequiredException; Request ID: NWPB863XQQJV86T2; S3 Extended Request ID: XC5qnepPTZxI0mzF6K3epFPIXpYn+iJiivZqSRjeZ4hR7yVZRAKJT0laFpGZ4twOZYOrusfaZBc=; Proxy: null) (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of steps to build a CI/CD that works. You have to make sure that you follow each step and all the config settings. The best advice is to follow theses AWS tutorials step by step. I followed these a few weeks ago and they work.

[Tutorial: Create a simple pipeline (S3 bucket)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-s3.html)

[Tutorial: Create a simple pipeline (CodeCommit repository)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html)